# How to specify the name of a gpiochip in the device-tree?

Tags: linux, gpio, device-tree

I'm working on an embedded linux system with quite a few IO lines, which i want to access using libgpiod. To make things easier, it would be great if i could search for the various gpiochips by name, but unfortunately the output of gpiodetect looks like this:

```
gpiochip0 [ff708000.gpio] (29 lines)
gpiochip1 [ff709000.gpio] (29 lines)
gpiochip2 [ff70a000.gpio] (27 lines)
gpiochip3 [pca9534] (8 lines)
gpiochip4 [pca9534] (8 lines)
gpiochip5 [pca9534] (8 lines)
gpiochip6 [pca9534] (8 lines)
gpiochip7 [pca9534] (8 lines)
gpiochip8 [pca9534] (8 lines)
```

I want to access the GPIOs of the PCA9534 IO-expanders, which - as you can see - all have the exact same name.

I know i can assign a name to each individual line, but what about the chip?
Is there a way to specify the name of a gpiochip in the device-tree?

EDIT:
Here is a part of the device tree, with a few of the IO-expanders

```
i2c_mux: i2cmux@70 {
    compatible = "nxp,pca9543";
    reg = <0x70>;
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;

    ext0: i2c@0 {
        reg = <0x00>;
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        ext0_id0: gpio@38 {
            compatible = "nxp,pca9534";
            reg = <0x38>;
            gpio-controller;
            #gpio-cells = <2>;
            ngpios = <8>;
        };

        ext0_id1: gpio@39 {
            compatible = "nxp,pca9534";
            reg = <0x39>;
            gpio-controller;
            #gpio-cells = <2>;
            ngpios = <8>;
        };

        ext0_gpio_out: gpio@3A {
            compatible = "nxp,pca9534";
            reg = <0x3A>;
            gpio-controller;
            #gpio-cells = <2>;
            ngpios = <8>;
        };
    };
};
```

EDIT:
I tested with kernel version 5.6-rc6, and now the output of gpiodetect is more reasonable:

```
gpiochip0 [ff708000.gpio] (29 lines)
gpiochip1 [ff709000.gpio] (29 lines)
gpiochip2 [ff70a000.gpio] (27 lines)
gpiochip3 [2-0038] (8 lines)
gpiochip4 [2-0039] (8 lines)
gpiochip5 [2-003a] (8 lines)
gpiochip6 [2-003b] (8 lines)
gpiochip7 [3-0038] (8 lines)
gpiochip8 [3-0039] (8 lines)
```

The version of libgpiod (in both cases) is 1.4.1, the output of `ls -l /sys/class/gpio` is

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           0 Mar 12 14:00 .
drwxr-xr-x   32 root     root           0 Jan  1  2001 ..
--w-------    1 root     root        4.0K Mar 12 14:00 export
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Mar 12 14:00 gpiochip1915 -> ../../devices/platform/sopc@0/ffc05000.i2c/i2c-1/i2c-3/3-0039/gpio/gpiochip1915
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Mar 12 14:00 gpiochip1923 -> ../../devices/platform/sopc@0/ffc05000.i2c/i2c-1/i2c-3/3-0038/gpio/gpiochip1923
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Mar 12 14:00 gpiochip1931 -> ../../devices/platform/sopc@0/ffc05000.i2c/i2c-1/i2c-2/2-003b/gpio/gpiochip1931
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Mar 12 14:00 gpiochip1939 -> ../../devices/platform/sopc@0/ffc05000.i2c/i2c-1/i2c-2/2-003a/gpio/gpiochip1939
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Mar 12 14:00 gpiochip1947 -> ../../devices/platform/sopc@0/ffc05000.i2c/i2c-1/i2c-2/2-0039/gpio/gpiochip1947
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Mar 12 14:00 gpiochip1955 -> ../../devices/platform/sopc@0/ffc05000.i2c/i2c-1/i2c-2/2-0038/gpio/gpiochip1955
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Mar 12 14:00 gpiochip1963 -> ../../devices/platform/sopc@0/ff70a000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip1963
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Mar 12 14:00 gpiochip1990 -> ../../devices/platform/sopc@0/ff709000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip1990
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           0 Mar 12 14:00 gpiochip2019 -> ../../devices/platform/sopc@0/ff708000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip2019
--w-------    1 root     root        4.0K Mar 12 14:00 unexport
```

Unfortunately upgrading to version 5.6 isn't really an option for me at this point in time, so i guess i'll just have to hard-code the gpiochip ids into my application

Comment: Second field (in the the square brackets) is a name of the *device instance*. See, what I have `gpiochip0 [0000:00:0c.0] (192 lines)
gpiochip1 [spi-PRP0001:01] (4 lines)
gpiochip2 [i2c-INT3491:00] (16 lines)
gpiochip3 [i2c-INT3491:01] (16 lines)
gpiochip4 [i2c-INT3491:02] (16 lines)
gpiochip5 [i2c-INT3491:03] (16 lines)`. It means that for PCA9534 chips you have rather wrong description that brings you into the same device.

Comment: @0andriy That's interesting, and resembles a little more closely what i want. I've added a part of my device tree, hoping that someone might spot any errors i might have made (even though i basically just copied the example of the PCA953x driver)

Comment: What kernel version do you use?

Comment: I'm on version 4.14.126 from [altera's github page](https://github.com/altera-opensource/linux-socfpga) (which is their most recent version with the PREEMPT_RT patchset)

Comment: I tested with 5.6-rc6 and it works as expected (i've added the relevant data to my post). However, a kernel upgrade of this magnitude is something i can't really do, especially since i need a realtime enabled kernel. So i guess i'm stuck hard-coding the ids into my application (and hoping that, if we ever do upgrade the kernel, those ids don't change)

Comment: Okay, i think i got a viable solution... There's a teeny-tiny bugfix for the pca953x driver, that i'll just backport into my version. It's literally just one line of code, so that shouldn't be too risky. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @0andriy

Comment: Submitted: https://lore.kernel.org/stable/20200318145722.48478-1-andriy.shevchenko@linux.intel.com/T/#u

Comment: Yeah, that's the one... now it works as expected for my kernel version :-). Thanks again for the help, the post can be closed now

Comment: Thank you for bug report, please don't remove post, at least till the patch makes stable releases.

Comment: Don't worry, i won't delete it